# How to remove a summoned potion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I summoned a no gravity potion in my world and don't know how to remove it. Is there any command I can type to get it removed? I used this command to summon it:

```
summon minecraft:potion ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,CustomName:"\"firewandwater\"",Potion:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}}
```

Comment: What was the command to summon the potion? Please [edit] your post to provide it.

Comment: /summon minecraft:potion ^ ^ ^1 {NoGravity:1,CustomName:"\"firewandwater\"",Potion:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}}

Answer (score 1):

This answer is no longer valid and will be edited later.

Yes, you can use either a command to remove all lingering potions, or just the ones within a certain distance of your player.

To remove all area-effect-clouds:

```
kill @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud]
```

To remove area-effect-clouds within a 10 block radius of the player:

```
kill @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud, distance=..10]
```

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 yes indeed, I thought I had copied it, I was wrong. It is now fixed

Comment: I used this command: /summon minecraft:potion ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,CustomName:"\"firewandwater\"",Potion:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}}. it would'nt be removed with your command

Comment: On second thought, are you sure this is valid? The asker has summoned a flying potion bottle, not an area-effect-cloud.

Comment: This is correct @ExpertCoder14 I'll update my answer when I have time.